# Rigid field of characteristic 0 with non-trivial endomorphisms

Tags: field-theory

Does there exist a field of characteristic 0 that has no automorphisms other than the identity but has endomorphisms other than the identity? In characteristic $p$, one can take the function field of a curve with no automorphisms and then Frobenius would define an endomorphism but I am not sure about characteristic 0.

I do not know many interesting ways of producing fields, pretty much only algebraic closure and completion. Algebraically closed fields always have automorphisms so they are not going to work [[1]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2092817/693243). The completions of $\mathbb{Q}$ at non-trivial places have no endomorphisms so they are not going to work either [[2]](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3312280/693243).